# msearch not working with bool must

Tags: full-text-search, elasticsearch

Elasticsearch version - .90.1

The following works perfectly.

```
cat names
{"index":"events","type":"news"}
{"query":{"term":{"Type":"MarketEvent"}}}
{"query":{"term":{"Type":"MarketEvent"}}}

curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_msearch'  --data-binary @names
```

The following also works

```
{"index":"events","type":"news"}
{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"query_string":{"query":"*","fields":["Events.Event"],"default_operator":"AND"}},{"term":{"Type":"MarketEvent"}}]}}}
```

But queries with more than 1 bool doesn't work -

```
cat names
{"index":"events","type":"news"}
{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"query_string":{"query":"*","fields":["Events.Event"],"default_operator":"AND"}},{"term":{"Type":"MarketEvent"}}]}}}
{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"query_string":{"query":"*","fields":["Events.Event"],"default_operator":"AND"}},{"term":{"Type":"MarketEvent"}}]}}}

curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_msearch'  --data-binary @names
{"error":"must doesn't support arrays"}
```

Am not seeing any log for this in logs ( not in DEBUG mode too)
Is this a bug ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `_msearch` query should have the following format:

```
header\n
body\n
header\n
body\n
```

In the first and the last queries the second header is missing. The error is not generated for the first query only because of the way the header is parsed. For this query to work the `names` file should be changed into

```
{"index":"events","type":"news"}
{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"query_string":{"query":"*","fields":["Events.Event"],"default_operator":"AND"}},{"term":{"Type":"MarketEvent"}}]}}}
{"index":"events","type":"news"}
{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"query_string":{"query":"*","fields":["Events.Event"],"default_operator":"AND"}},{"term":{"Type":"MarketEvent"}}]}}}
```